# Android convert date synced in string format from SQL to Sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, date, time

Basically I have synced dates using a webservice from a SQL server and what I have is this string `/Date(1422217800000+0330)/` I know it's in milliseconds, but how can I convert it to `Date` in android without parsing it bymyself?

Comment: at least leave a comment and say why you down voted my problem !

Answer (score 1):

Since no one manned up to answer my question or at least tell me why down voted my problem, here is my solution, for future reference:

```
public static String jsonDateConverter(String jsonDate){

        String milliseconds = jsonDate.replace("/Date(", "");
        int indx1 = milliseconds.indexOf(")")-5;
        milliseconds = milliseconds.substring(0,indx1);
        long l = Long.valueOf(milliseconds);
        Date d =  new Date(l);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        return sdf.format(d));
    }
```

so the answer would be `no` and I had to parse the entry json string

Comment: This worked really well with converting .NET json date to Android JSON date. You can attach your solution to a GSON factory w/RETROFIT: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTimeConvertAdapter()).create(); and then inside the deserialize method, just call  return DateHelper.jsonDateConverter(json.getAsString()); Thanks!!!!